# Powerpoint vba - copying table from excel

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have been trying to write a macro that updates a presentation through powerpoint vba using tables from excel.

**Here is what I am doing**

- The code first deletes all pictures in the presentation,
- Then opens the excel workbook, copys a named range and pastes into the correct slide.

This exact code was working fine two days ago and is now saying the **object is out of range** for copying the range **"PL"**. Any help or tips would be great as this is my first time using powerpoint vba.

```
valnPath = "G:\valnpath\"
PriorPath = "G:\Priorpath\"

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(valnPath & "Presentation Tables 1208.xlsx", True, False)
Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    XL.DisplayAlerts = False
    XL.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    XL.Range("PL").Copy

 ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Select
 Application.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    XL.DisplayAlerts = False
    XL.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    XL.Range("AvE").Copy

 ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Select
 Application.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

 Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 XL.Quit
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Please help me with this,

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `GetObject()` to get a second reference to Excel after you already opened a new instance using `CreateObject()` ? If there are multiple instances of excel open then there's no guarantee as to which instance will be returned by `GetObject()` (and it could even return a 'hidden' instance), so you'd be better off sticking with your original `xlApp` reference.

Comment: I dont have a particular reason why I am doing this, as mentioned, this is my first attempt at powerpoint vba - I thought that I would have to 'call' the excel spreadsheet as such to copy from it. So instead of `XL.Range("PL").Copy`, I would use `xlApp.Range("PL").Copy` Thanks for your input, Ill try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
valnPath = "G:\valnpath\"
PriorPath = "G:\Priorpath\"

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
   .Visible = True
   .DisplayAlerts = False
   .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(valnPath & _
                       "Presentation Tables 1208.xlsx", True, False)

xlApp.Range("PL").Copy
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Select
Application.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

xlApp.Range("AvE").Copy
ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Select
Application.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

xlWorkBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: +1, I would have given this answer but I had to go for a bit and you had already made a comment to the effect. The only other possible issue is that the workbook actually doesn't include the named ranges.

Comment: Seems like this has fixed my problem. Really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: @user1775757 - if this fixed your problem (as you said), you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer capturing values in ArrayList or array and then consuming them in PowerPoint slides.

Use this sample code to understand the process.

```
Function GetDataFromExcel()
    
    ' CreateObject ("Excel.Application")
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xObjFD As FileDialog
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xObjFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    xObjFD.Title = "Select the excel file location " & FileType
    
    With xObjFD
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb", 1
        .Show
        
        ' Selection is not null
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            xFilePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        Dim xlWorkBook As Object, valueCollected As String, _
        rowCount As Integer : rowCount = 4
        Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xFilePath, True, False)
        xlWorkBook.Activate
        Set ArrayValues = New ArrayList
        
loopToCollectData:
        On Error GoTo er
        valueCollected = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4).Range("B" & rowCount).Value
        If valueCollected <> "" Then
            ArrayValues.Add valueCollected
            rowCount = rowCount + 3
            GoTo loopToCollectData
        End If
    End With
    
    xlWorkBook.Close
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Exit Function

er:
    xlWorkBook.Close
    xlApp.Visible = False
    MsgBox "Please select the relevant input file!"
    End     

End Function
```

Also, capture the range in an array and then consume it as required. Something like this.

```
bColumnArray = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2)))
```